# Как правильно составить запрос

Tags: select

Ситуация следующая -

В БД есть две таблицы, одна со статьями - **`posts`**, вторая с данными юзера - **`users`**.

Для страницы всех статей запрос в БД работает правильно, выводит данные с двух таблиц.

```
SELECT posts.*, users.name, users.city 
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN users ON posts.user_id=users.id 
WHERE posts.type='post' 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Отдельная статья открывается через `$_GET (post.php?id=<?php echo $art['id']; ?>)` и запрос на странице отдельной статьи сейчас такой -

```
"SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = " . (int) $_GET['id']
```

Здесь подтягиваются данные только из таблицы **`posts`**

Вопрос - как правильно составить запрос к БД на странице вывода отдельной статьи чтобы подтягивать данные из таблиц **`users`** и **`posts`** к примеру `users.name`?

/-/-/-/-///

Спасибо, все работает. 
Возник еще вопрос. В таблице *users* есть столбик **stream_profile** где содержатся расширенные данные профиля юзера в таком формате

a:10:{s:5:"photo";s:14:"123456789.png";s:5:"cover";s:14:"987654321.jpg";s:4:"city";s:38:"АДРЕС";s:4:"site";s:21:"site.ua";s:2:"vk";s:0:"";s:7:"twitter";s:29:"twitter.com/";s:2:"fb";s:35:"facebook.com";s:6:"google";s:49:"plus.google.com";s:9:"instagram";s:37:"instagram.com";s:7:"youtube";s:0:"";}

Скрин данных  в столбце - > https://api.monosnap.com/rpc/file/download?id=HwOqDVzIOyrJF6yELYb8znc2dU54CS

Запрос к БД на странице вывода -

$articles = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT posts.*, users.name, users.phone, users.stream_profile, users.city FROM posts LEFT JOIN users ON posts.user_id=users.id WHERE posts.id= ".(int) $_GET['id']."");

работает правильно, но вывод картинки из *users.stream_profile* не работает -

img src="/ uploads / < ? php echo $art['stream_profile']['cover']; ? > " alt=""
Ничего не выводится

Вопрос - Как правильно прописать вывод из **stream_profile** данных *photo* или *cover*

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Просто в `WHERE` вашего первого запроса добавьте `AND posts.id= ".(int) $_GET['id']."`

Comment: Спасибо все сработало! Если не затруднит гляньте дополнение к вопросу. Появился еще один нюанс. Заранее спасибо.